# Tensorflow strings custom function replace?

Tags: python, regex, tensorflow, regexp-replace

I am creating a custom standardize function for the `TextVectorization` layer in my model.
In my custom function, I need to perform custom replacement of each word, like the following example:

```py
def customStandadize(text):
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, r'\w+', customReplace)
```

where `customReplace` is like this:

```py
def customReplace(text):
  return text + str(text.index('k'))
```

Can anyone help me with this, I tried backreferencing like below but it didn't work

```py
def customStandadize(text):
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, r'(\w+)', customReplace(r'\1'))
```

Comment: Why don't you describe the problem you are trying to solve?  Your custom replace function seems to make no sense.  I would describe its function as 'Find the position of the first occurrence of a "k" and interpret that position number as an ASCII character and append it to the text string.'

Comment: I think you need to provide some input/output to further explain the goal

Comment: It is not possible as `regexp_replace` does not support a callable as replacement argument. Chec yourself [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_replace).

Comment: @ChrisMaurer In my original problem, I am performing lemmatization to each word, and want to perform that in my `customStandardize` function.